# I get $.cookie but it do not work?

Tags: jquery

i get cookie.js at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
when i call

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#abc").click(function() {
  var a = $("#text").val();
  var b = $("#password").val();
  alert("asdasdsd  ");
  $.cookie("user",a);
  alert($.cookie("user"));
  
 });
 
   
});
```

```html
<form>
 user: <input id="text"> </input>
 pass: <input id="password" type="password"></input>
 <button id="abc">submit</button>
</form>
```

it do not work for me.
In my lab, i import Jquery, cookie.js.
Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yvd7p7x4/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Check `console ` for errors

Comment: it works in this link but in my lab it is undefined

Comment: clear cache of your bowser and recheck!

Comment: have you tried `$("#abc").submit(function() { //your code }`

Comment: - when i set and show it in console : console.log($.cookie("name","333")); it shows name=333

-But when i call name : console.log($.cookie("name")); -> undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find answer for my question: cookies does not working in my Chrome! when i use firefox , it done well! (chrome does not work with localhost(use domain)